# How can I change the background color of a td in BootstrapVue table based on a function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

How can I change the background color  of a td in BootstrapVue table based on a function that will check the td value and after this, return the color

I pretend change the color of the td based on the value of the td. But I cant chanfe the color of a specific td based on a function.. I just got it changing the value of the entire row :/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.